# NoneType Error self.widget.insert

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to have an output frame in my application. When I run it i get the error: `NoneType object has no attribute insert` on `self.widget.insert('end', string)`. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import Tkinter as tk
import sys

class Test(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        toolbar = tk.Frame(self).grid()
        tk.Button(self, text="print to stdout", command=self.print_stdout).grid()

        self.text= tk.Text(self).grid()
        sys.stdout= Output(self.text)


    def print_stdout(self):
        print "Hello"
        print "This is test"

class Output(object):
    def __init__(self, widget):
        self.widget = widget

    def write(self,string):
        self.widget.insert('end', string)

app = Test()
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem occurs on this line:

```
self.text= tk.Text(self).grid()
```

`grid` doesn't explicitly `return` anything, so this is effectively setting `self.text = None`. This value is then passed to `Output.__init__` and eventually accessed in `write`.

Split it into two steps instead:

```
 self.text = tk.Text(self)
 self.text.grid()
```