# Python AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm relatively new to python and as a small project I've been trying to apply a basic gui to my caesar cipher program using tkinter. I sort of understand what's wrong but have no clue as to how to fix it. Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

```
from tkinter import *
from logos import *        

class MainMenu():

    def __init__(self,master):

        self.master = master
        self.master.geometry("500x500")
        self.master.title("L337 H4X0R")
        self.master.configure(bg = "#303030 ")

        self.button = Button(self.master, text = "Encrypt", fg = "green", bg = 'black', command = self.goToEncrypt).place(x=100, y=150)
        self.button = Button(self.master, text = "Decrypt", fg = "green", bg = "black", command = self.goToDecrypt).place(x=250, y=150)
        self.button = Button(self.master, text = "Hack", fg = "green", bg = "black", command = self.goToHacks).place(x=400, y=150)


    def goToEncrypt(self):
        self.master.withdraw()
        root2 = Toplevel(self.master)
        GUII = Encipher(root2)

    def goToDecrypt(self):
        #root3 = Toplevel(self.master)
        #GUII = Decipher(root3)
        pass

    def goToHacks(self):
        #root4 = Toplevel(self.master)
        #GUIIkiv = HAXOR(root4)
        pass


class Encipher():

    def __init__(self,master):

        self.key = IntVar()
        self.message = StringVar()

        self.master = master
        self.master.geometry("500x500")
        self.master.title("L337 H4X0R")
        self.master.configure(bg = "#303030 ")

        self.label1 = Label(self.master, text="Key",bg = "black", fg = "green").place(x=20, y = 40)
        self.label2 = Label(self.master, text = "Input",bg = "black", fg = "green").place(x=20, y =120)
        self.label3 = Label(self.master, text = "Output", bg = "black", fg ="green").place(x=300, y= 120)
        self.spinbox= Spinbox(self.master,from_=1, to=61, state = NORMAL, textvariable = self.key, bg ="black", fg="green").place(x=100, y=40)
        self.text = Text(self.master, bg = "white", wrap = WORD, height = 15, width = 20).place(x= 20, y=150)
        self.text2 = Text(self.master, bg = "white", wrap = WORD, height = 15, width = 20, state = DISABLED).place(x= 300, y=150)
        self.button = Button(self.master, text = "Enter", bg = "black", fg = "green", command = self.enter).place(x = 20, y=400)

    def enter(self):
        self.message = self.text.get('0.0', END+"-1c")
        self.text2(self.master, state=NORMAL)
        self.text2.insert(self.master,'1.0', text=encrypt(self.message, self.key))
        self.text2(self.master, state=DISABLED)

def main():
    root = Tk()
    GUI = MainMenu(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When I press the enter button it displays the following message:

```
C:\Users\Karl\Documents\Python>app.py
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Programming\Python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1482, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Karl\Documents\Python\App.py", line 56, in enter
    self.message = self.text.get('0.0', END+"-1c")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: More-or-less exactly the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23625407/nonetype-error-self-widget-insert/23625549#23625549

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that you are doing this:

```
self.text = Text(self.master, bg = "white", wrap = WORD, height = 15, width = 20).place(x= 20, y=150)
```

So in `self.text` you are storing not the `Text` object but the result of the `place` method (which is `None`).

You should do this instead:

```
self.text = Text(self.master, bg = "white", wrap = WORD, height = 15, width = 20)
self.text.place(x= 20, y=150)
```

Same for all other places where you create and call `place()` in the same line

Comment: Applies also to grid() method =)